# Rails nested set with overridden attributes and associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, overriding, acts-as-nested-set

Is  there a nested_set gem that will let you inherit a parent's attributes and associations and let you override specific attributes, storing the overrides independent of the parent?